# HTML5 Video Toggle Mute On Click?

Tags: jquery, html5-video, toggle, mute

I'm trying to toggle mute by clicking on the video.

I am able to un-mute the video when clicking using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("video").prop('muted', true);

    $("video").click( function (){
        if( $("video").prop('muted', true) )
        {
            $("video").prop('muted', false)
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Edf8m/7/

Now I just want to be able to click again and it be muted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to solve your problem with a simple boolean toggle.

```
$("video").click(function () {
    $(this).prop("muted", !$(this).prop("muted"));
});
```

Comment: You sir, are a star. I've been going mad trying to get that working.